# Scaling an image with "Drawing Tools" primitives on it

Tags: image-processing, image

Imagine I doodle with the "Drawing tools" pen, or place lines on an image after importing it.  Now say I want to scale this image by some constant factor $C$ while maintaining the same aspect ratio.  How can I correspondingly scale my "Drawing tools" objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to scale it is graphically. Grab the lower right hand corner of the drawing you have created and drag to make it larger or smaller. If you want to do it programmatically, name the drawing something like `img`, and then enter

```
Show[img, ImageSize -> 600]
```

replacing the "600" with the desired size.